# I want to convert the scss file into each css file in NEXT.js

Tags: sass, next.js

I want the CSS file to be converted to the CSS file.
But I don't know how to set it up.

I would like to use the CSS file converted from the _document.tsx file using Link.

[image]

I have never used NEXT JS or React. If you tell me the keyword, I want to find it and try it.

I searched a lot on Google, but I couldn't find the way I wanted.

Is this impossible?

Comment: 시발 아무도 모르나.., 답이 없는건가.... 이거 자체가..

Comment: 양키새끼들 다 코로나 걸려 뒤져라..... ㅠㅜ